# SQLAlchemy relation does not exist when importing db

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am migrating to a new database with SQLAlchemy and want to create the database and tables using `db.create_all()`. Now I am getting the following error

> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "Image" does not exist

when I am trying to import `db`. The error occurs because I'm creating a global variable a service of the app depends on by executing a query `Image.query.all()`. So practically, the variable is created when the app starts. Of course this does not work now because the data structure is not yet in place.

How can I get around this issue without having to temporarily commenting out the code? Basically I want to simply be able to conduct the database setup without this query being executed.

Comment: Try to execute db.create_all() in a app context, i.e. with app.app_context(): db.create_all(); if this does not help, please share the relevant code.